# Jquery filter list by clicking link and show it in table

Tags: jquery, filter, href, clicking

I'm trying to get propper search by href values , but when i click on each value it shows me blank table,
and index of values is always 0. I tried literally everything and none of that worked. I think that the main problem is in the script ,  because it always shows me blank index of each element.

Can someone tell me what i am missing?

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>  // This script is working
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {        
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  
}

.odd {
      background: #5a95ee;
}
.even{
  background: #7eb9e0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search.." style="float: right; width: 500px;" value="">
<br><br>

<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Predmet</th>
    <th>Tip</th>
    <th>Nastavnik</th>
    <th>Grupe</th>
    <th>Dan</th>
    <th>Termin</th>
    <th>Ucionica</th>
  </tr>
  
  </thead>
{% for raspored in rasporedi %}
  <tbody id="myTable">

  <tr class="{{ loop.cycle('odd', 'even') }}">
      
    <td > {{raspored['predmet']}}</td>
    <td>{{raspored['tip']}}</td>
    <td >{{raspored['nastavnik']}}</td>
    <td>{{raspored['grupe']}}</td>           // Python list ( data from mongodb )
    <td>{{raspored['dan']}}</td>
    <td>{{raspored['termin']}}</td>
    <td>{{raspored['ucionica']}}</td>
  </tr>
 
  </tbody>
  {% endfor %}


   
</table>


<br> <br>

<table style="width: 400px;" style="margin:0 auto;">
    <thead>
    <tr >
     
      <th>Nastavnik</th>
      <th>Ucionica</th>
    </tr>
    
    </thead>
  {% for raspored in dr %}
    <tbody id="myTabledva">
  
    <tr>
        
      <td class="nastavnik {{ loop.cycle('odd', 'even') }}"  > <a href="#" >{{raspored['nastavnik']}}</a></td>  
      <td class="ucionica {{ loop.cycle('odd', 'even') }}">  <a href="#" >{{raspored['ucionica']}}</a></td>
    </tr>
   
  </tbody>
  
    
  

  
  <script>    // Something is wrong with this script but i don't know what

      $(document).on("click", ".nastavnik", function(){

   var nastavnik = $("#myInput").val($(this).text());  

 
     $("#myTable tr").filter(function() { 
      
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(nastavnik) > -1 )

     });
    
 });
 
   </script> 

    {% endfor %}
  
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

```
  <script>    // Something is wrong with this script but i don't know what

      $(document).on("click", ".nastavnik", function(){

   var nastavnik = $("#myInput").val($(this).text());  

 
     $("#myTable tr").filter(function() { 
      
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(nastavnik) > -1 )

     });
    
 });
 
   </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You've misunderstood what `filter()` does. You seem to believe that it will show/hide elements, which its not its job. It merely filters down a set of matched elements to a subset. Have a read of [its documentation](https://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: Thank you. So , if filter is not a propper function , what should i use to show clicked value on table (live search) ?

Comment: It is a proper function - it just doesn't do what you thought it did. You need to filter *then* either `show()` or `hide()` on the collection.

Comment: So instead toggle , i need to show() ? 
 $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(nastavnik) > -1 )

it will be :
 $(this).show($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(nastavnik) > -1 ) ?

Comment: Not quite. You may need some more jQuery tutorials. You're assuming too much, e.g. by thinking your can pass arguments to `show()`. jQuery works by chaining - first you derive a collection of elements, then you do stuff to them by chaining a method to them. So: $('.some.selector').filter(function() { /* ... */ }).hide()`, for example. `toggle()` is equivalent to `show()`/`hide()` so yes, you can use that too.

Comment: Thank you for your answers , i'm absolutelly new to jquery so i don't know what is exact solution to my problem.  If you can put some solution i would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:

```
$(document).on("click", ".nastavnik", function() {
    let nastavnik = $("#myInput").val(); //<-- get, not set, the entere val
    $("#myTable tr").show().filter(function() {  
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(nastavnik.toLowerCase()) == -1;
    }).hide();
 });
```

Logic:

1. Get the entered value
2. Get all table rows - show all by default
3. Filter table rows to those that **don't** contain the entered search.
4. Hide those rows.

Comment: I tried it now , it doesn't work. It is showing a whole table instead clicked text.

Comment: There is no reason that should not work. Please reproduce the problem in a JS Fiddle or similar, using my code, to demonstrate.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mristic2719s/svL0ydta/7/
Here is jsfiddle , when you click on "Some teacher" it isn't  shown (refreshed) in table.

Comment: and sorry, this is collab link https://jsfiddle.net/5pnxa2kw/#&togetherjs=4yhzuA9g3p